# Как отключить взаимодействия с webView

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы прям ничего не работало не свайпы не нажатия  (полное безразличие к любым взаимодействиям )

```
webView.setEnabled(false);
 webView.setFocusable(false);
  не работают
```

.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        
        
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Точно сработает положить поверх WebView любую прозрачную вьюху с focusable и clickable со значением true

Comment: как наложить текст вью на WebView

Comment: Лучше просто View. Чтобы наложить замените контейнер на FrameLayout и поместите под WebView просто View

Answer (score 0):

Вот так меня устроило спасиб

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
    
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </WebView>
    
    
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:onClick="x" />
        
    </FrameLayout >
```

.

```
public void x (View view){}
```